# Javascript equivalent to Excel's Text function

Tags: javascript

Is there a library in Javascript with an equivalent to Excel's (or Google spreasheet) [Text](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Text-Function.html) function ?

Answer (score 1):

No , You need to create your own function for each usage like date Formatting, Time Formatting etc.

For that in Javascript there are many functions like filter,map,replace which can help you to manipulate the array or a string easily.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but [Format.JS](http://formatjs.io/) seems like it should work well. From the [site](http://formatjs.io/):

> FormatJS is a modular collection of JavaScript libraries for
>   internationalization that are focused on formatting numbers, dates,
>   and strings for displaying to people.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this document [JavaScript Text formatting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting) helps you solve your problem a little bit.

You can use [JavaScript isNAN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to choose type of format (Number | Date | ...). For example:

```
if (isNAN(5259)) {
    var msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var date = new Date(msPerDay * 5259);
    var options = { year: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", timeZoneName: "short" };
    var americanDateTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format;
    console.log(americanDateTime(date));
} else {
    var gasPrice = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {style: "currency", currency: "USD", minimumFractionDigits: 3}); 
    console.log(gasPrice.format(5259));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two JavaScript libraries which I use for certain operations.

UnderscoreJS (http://underscorejs.org) : For manipulation of Array, String and Object.

MomentJS (http://momentjs.com) : For date / time related operations.

I think you can take a look (if you have't already).